# Image of a map on $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I want to determine the image of the map below (actually the generators of the image)

$$\alpha: \mathbb{R}[x,y]^4 \to \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle y \rangle^{r+1}} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x \rangle^{r+1}} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle y \rangle^{r+1}} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x \rangle^{r+1}}$$ defined by $\alpha(f,g,h,t) = (f+t+\langle y \rangle^{r+1},g-f+\langle x \rangle^{r+1},h-g+\langle y \rangle^{r+1},-h-t+\langle x \rangle^{r+1})$.

What I have tried is, if $(a+\langle y \rangle^{r+1},b+\langle x \rangle^{r+1},c+\langle y \rangle^{r+1},d+\langle x \rangle^{r+1}) \in \text{Im} 
\space \alpha$, then we have

$a+\langle y \rangle^{r+1} = f+t+\langle y \rangle^{r+1}$,

$b+\langle x \rangle^{r+1} = g-f+\langle y \rangle^{r+1}$,

$c+\langle y \rangle^{r+1} = h-g+\langle y \rangle^{r+1}$ and

$d+\langle x \rangle^{r+1} = -h-t+\langle y \rangle^{r+1}$.

Using this equalities, we have the relations:

$f+t = a+p.y^{r+1}$,

$g-f = b+q.x^{r+1}$,

$h-g = c+r.y^{r+1}$ and

$-h-t = d+s.x^{r+1}$ for some $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

Here since $(f+t)+(g-f)+(-h-t)=-(h-g)$, I can say $-b-d+(-q-s).x^{r+1} = a+c+(p+r).y^{r+1}$.

Finally I can write $-b-d+m.x^{r+1} = a+c+n.y^{r+1}$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Here is the place where I have stucked. How can I determine the generators of $\text{Im}\space \alpha$?

Comment: Any ideas please?